# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable error in matoplotlib animation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been trying to code an animation using matplolibs FuncAnimation to create a model like the picture below where each frame a circle changes color from white to grey and vice versa. The picture:

[The model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSAQd.png)

Below is the code. Consider h as a list containing to separate lists, the first contains the circle to change in each frame and the second the starting colors of the circles in the form of separate 'k' and 'w' strings. An example for h:

```
[[1,3,4,1.....]['k','w','k','w','w'....]]
```

The code:

```
n=5
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(n,n))
x =[i%n+1 for i in range(0,n**2)]
y =[i/n+1 for i in range(n**2)]
h=giving_data_for_visual(2,n,3,1,2)
cl=h[1]
colors=''
for i in cl:
    colors+=i
changes_list=h[0]
scat=plt.scatter(x, y,s=50,facecolors=colors, alpha=0.5)

def update(frame):
    global colors,change_list
    t=(cl[changes_list[frame]]=='k')
    cl[changes_list[frame]]='k' if t else 'w'
    colors=cl
    scat.set_facecolors(colors)

ani=animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=10, blit=True,frames=len(changes_list))
plt.show()
```

The imports are using are as follows (some aren't meant for this part of the program):

```
from random import randint
from random import uniform
from math import exp
from math import log
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import std
from matplotlib import animation
```

However when i run the code only the first frame appear (something similiar to model i posted above) and when i close its window this error appears:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yael\Desktop\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.2\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Yael\Desktop\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.2\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 587, in callit
func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Yael\Desktop\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.2\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 143, in _on_timer
TimerBase._on_timer(self)
  File "C:\Users\Yael\Desktop\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.2\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 1290, in _on_timer
ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Yael\Desktop\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.2\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 925, in _step
still_going = Animation._step(self, *args)
  File "C:\Users\Yael\Desktop\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.2\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 784, in _step
self._draw_next_frame(framedata, self._blit)
  File "C:\Users\Yael\Desktop\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.2\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 802, in _draw_next_frame
self._pre_draw(framedata, blit)
  File "C:\Users\Yael\Desktop\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.2\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 815, in _pre_draw
self._blit_clear(self._drawn_artists, self._blit_cache)
  File "C:\Users\Yael\Desktop\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.2\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 853, in _blit_clear
    axes = set(a.axes for a in artists)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I cant solve this bug. Thanks in advance for any help :).

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation of `FuncAnimation`](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation) says that the `update` function should return the changed artists:

```
If blit=True, func and init_func should return an iterable of drawables to clear.
```

You might want to change your function to

```
def update(frame):
    global colors,change_list
    t=(cl[changes_list[frame]]=='k')
    cl[changes_list[frame]]='k' if t else 'w'
    colors=cl
    scat.set_facecolors(colors)
    return scat
```

Note the last line that I added to your code.

Comment: Thank you. Now i feel awfully stupid for missing a return.

Comment: Well, it's not clear that the function needs to return something at all.